# Loading processing js via jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, processing.js

I'm having trouble loading a processing js script via a jquery ajax call.  The sketch runs fine in its own file but when i load it into a div it doesn't work.  Do I need to init the sketch somehow?  I've searched the Processing js docs but can't find it.  Thanks

The ugly test script

```
<a href="#" onclick="$.ajax({url: '/test',  context: document.body,  success: function(text){    $('#container').html(text);  }});">Test</a>
```

Where '/test' would contain

```
<script type="application/processing" data-processing-target="pjs">
// code here
</script>
<canvas width="760" height="500" id="pjs"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're fetching the source from a file, create a new Processing instance for the canvas you want it loaded into, instead:

```
Processing.loadSketchFromSources($('#pjs'), ['mysketch.pde']);
```

The second argument is an array because a sketch can consist of multiple source files.

If it's dynamic code, simply build a new Processing instance:

```
new Processing($('#pjs'), "/* full sketch code goes here. */");
```

Your post seems to suggest some level of control with respect to what the ajax call to "/test" generates, so I would have it simply generate the sketch code only, without the script and canvas tag, and have the ajax callback function generate the canvas element on the page, followed by a new Processing($('#canvasid'), callbackdata) call so that Processing.js loads the sketch code into the canvas you just made.

Comment: If you're doing rails js.erb's here's some sample code:

js = '<%= escape_javascript render :partial => "auto", :locals => {:data => @data} %>';
new Processing('processing-canvas2', js);

Note - it wouldn't work for me when I passed $('...') - just had to pass the id string of the element - no jquery bits